# Changing part of a template pack using a pre-written pack transformation

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic

Suppose you have something like

```
template <typename, typename, int, typename, int, typename...> struct P
```

and you want to reverse the `typename...` part only.  Now you've already written the generic reverse transformation:

```
// Reverse<Pack<Types...>>::type is Pack<Types'...>, where Types'... is Types... reversed.
template <typename, typename> struct ReverseHelper;

template <template <typename...> class P, typename Pack>
struct ReverseHelper<P<>, Pack> {
    using type = Pack;
};

template <template <typename...> class P, typename First, typename... Rest, typename... Types>
struct ReverseHelper<P<First, Rest...>, P<Types...>> : ReverseHelper<P<Rest...>, P<First, Types...>> {};

template <typename> struct Reverse;

template <template <typename...> class P, typename... Types>
struct Reverse<P<Types...>> : ReverseHelper<P<Types...>, P<>> {};
```

Of course, we could rewrite the above with `template <typename, typename, int, typename, int, typename...> class P` instead, namely:

```
template <typename, typename> struct ReverseHelper1;

template <template <typename, typename, int, typename, int, typename...> class P,
    typename U, typename V, int M, typename W, int N, typename Pack>
struct ReverseHelper1<P<U,V,M,W,N>, Pack> {
    using type = Pack;
};

template <template <typename, typename, int, typename, int, typename...> class P,
    typename U, typename V, int M, typename W, int N, typename First, typename... Rest, typename... Types>
struct ReverseHelper1<P<U,V,M,W,N, First, Rest...>, P<Types...>> : ReverseHelper<P<U,V,M,W,N, Rest...>, P<First, Types...>> {};

template <typename> struct Reverse1;

template <template <typename, typename, int, typename, int, typename...> class P,
    typename U, typename V, int M, typename W, int N, typename... Types>
struct Reverse1<P<U,V,M,W,N, Types...>> : ReverseHelper1<P<U,V,M,W,N, Types...>, P<U,V,M,W,N>> {};
```

Notice we are just repeating?  And then we would have to do this again and again for other template signatures if we want to do the same partial reversal thing.  So how to make the approach by using the original `Reverse` itself to avoid all this repetition?

For example, let's suppose we have

```
template <typename> struct Foo;
template <typename> struct Bar;

template <template <typename, typename, int, typename, int, typename...> class P,
    typename U, typename V, int M, typename W, int N, typename... Args>
struct Foo<P<U,V,M,W,N, Args...>> {};
```

Let's have `Foo<P<U,V,M,W,N, Args...>>` derive from `Bar<P<U,V,M,W,N, ArgsReversed...>>`.  How to accomplish this using the defined `Reverse` from above?

Note, it's not the same thing as

```
template <template <typename, typename, int, typename, int, typename> class P,
    typename U, typename V, int M, typename W, int N,
    template <typename...> class Q, typename... Args>
struct Foo<P<U,V,M,W,N, Q<Args...>>> : Bar<P<U,V,M,W,N, typename Reverse<Q<Args...>>::type>> {};
```

though I suspect accomplishing it is done something along the lines of this.  Of course, reversing is just an example.   We want to reuse any transformation to make the same transformation for only part of (any) larger template structure.

Comment: If you are going to metametaprogram, use `std::integral_constant` and other type wrappers around constants.

Comment: Would a macro based solution be ok?

Comment: @Yakk.  If macros is the only way to accomplish it sure.  But I thought there would be a way using templates only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way is to stop using `int` as arguments to templates.

Barring that, you can write metafunctions for a particular pattern of class and int types, and "lift" both the template and the instance to being about classes (where `int` is replaced with `integral_constant`), and operate on those (write "reverse types after N types" to get the reverse done).

Barring that, we can hand code for your particular pattern.

```
template<class...>struct types{using type=types;};

namespace details {
  template<class T, class types>
  struct replace_tail;
  template<class T, class types>
  using replace_tail_t = typename replace_tail<T,types>::type;

  template<class T>
  struct get_tail;
  template<class T>
  using get_tail_t = typename get_tail<T,types>::type;

  template<template <class, class, int, class, int, class...> class P, 
    class A, class B, int C, class D, int E, class...Fs,
    class... Ts
  >
  struct replace_tail<P<A,B,C,D,E,Fs...>,types<Ts...>> {
    using type = P<A,B,C,D,E,Ts...>;
  };
  template<template <class, class, int, class, int, class...> class P, 
    class A, class B, int C, class D, int E, class...Fs
  >
  struct get_tail<P<A,B,C,D,E,Fs...>>:types<Fs...>{};

  template<class T>
  using reverse_t = ReverseHelper<T>::type;
  template<class T>
  using reverse_tail = replace_tail_t < T, reverse_t<get_tail_t<T>> >;
}

using details::reverse_tail;
```

which may contain syntax errors.  The plan is to break it into 3 parts.

First, reversing a pack (you wrote this already).

Second, extracting the "tail" arguments to reverse from an instance into a pack.

Third, replacing the "tail" arguments with another pack.

Hooked together, we reverse the tail.  As a specializing `get_tail_t` and `replace_tail_t` for a new pattern of `template` arguments will make `reverse_tail_t` "just work".

Comment: I haven't made a full example of your code yet, but from glancing at it we successfully avoid having to rewrite `Reverse` (and `Rotate`, `RemoveHead`, etc...) for different template signatures for `P`, but new template signatures for `P` will require writing new specializations for `get_tail` and `replace_tail`, right?  Well, rewriting new 2 specializations for each new template signature is definitely better than rewriting all the new transformations at least.   I guess there is no way to avoid having to rewrite anything for any new `P`, i.e. there is no solution to handle all forms of `P`?

Comment: @prestokeys If your `P` lacked non-type template arguments, you could write a generic one.  You could also write code that 'lifted' each pattern of template to a non-type template, and 'lifted' the arguments of a template instance the same (each of these would require custom code for each *pattern* of template), then take your instance, lift it to pure type arguments, flip the tail (starting at N), then apply it back to the lifted template.  This approach might be easier if you had many such algorithms to work with.

Comment: However, again the real solution is in metaprogram friendly template code, stop using non-type template arguments.  `template<int X>using int_k = typename std::integral_constant<int, X>;`, and expect `int_k<N>` instead of `N` in that "slot".  Finally, note that the `P` in question is a *pattern* of template type and non-type arguments, not a specific template.

Answer (score -1):

Let's make a typelist:

```
template <typename...> struct typelist { };
```

You can get the N-th type of the typelist:

```
template <size_t N, typename> struct typelist_get;

template <typename T, typename ...Ts>
struct typelist_get<0, typelist<T, Ts...>>
{
  using type = T;
};

template <size_t N, typename T, typename ...Ts>
struct typelist_get<N, typelist<T, Ts...>>
  : typelist_get<N - 1, typelist<Ts...>>
{ };
```

You can reverse a typelist:

```
template <typename, typename> struct reverse_helper;

template <typename T, typename ...Ts, typename ...Rs>
struct reverse_helper<typelist<T, Ts...>, typelist<Rs...>>
  : reverse_helper<typelist<Ts...>, typelist<T, Rs...>>
{ };

template <typename ...Rs>
struct reverse_helper<typelist<>, typelist<Rs...>>
{
  using type = typelist<Rs...>;
};

template <typename T> struct typelist_reverse
  : reverse_helper<T, typelist<>>
{ };
```

We also need a index_sequence:

```
template <size_t...> struct index_sequence;
```

and a way to build an `index_sequence<0, 1, ..., N - 1>` for given N:

```
template <std::size_t N, std::size_t ...I>
struct index_sequence_builder
{
  using type = typename index_sequence_builder<N - 1, N - 1, I...>::type;
};

template <std::size_t ... I>
struct index_sequence_builder<0, I...>
{
  using type = index_sequence<I...>;
};


template <std::size_t N>
using make_index_sequence = typename index_sequence_builder<N>::type;
```

Let's say we have some variadic template class `Foo`:

```
template <typename ...Ts> struct Foo { };
```

Then we can reverse it as follows:

```
template <typename, typename> struct reverse_foo_impl;

template <typename ...Ts, size_t ...I>
struct reverse_foo_impl<Foo<Ts...>, index_sequence<I...>>
{
  using TL = typelist<Ts...>;
  using RTL = typename typelist_reverse<TL>::type;

  using type = Foo<typename typelist_get<I, RTL>::type...>;
};

template <typename> struct reverse_foo;

template <typename...Ts>
struct reverse_foo<Foo<Ts...>>
  : reverse_foo_impl<Foo<Ts...>, make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts)>>
{ };
```

Here, `TL` are the template parameters of `Foo` as typelist, `RTL` is the same typelist reversed. To extract the template parameters as pack, we need to create something like `typelist_get<0, RTL>::type, typelist_get<1, RTL>::type, ..., typelist_get<N - 1, RTL>::type`. This is accomplished using the index sequence where the expansion w.r.t. `I` exactly recreates that pattern.

In the end we can use it like this:

```
  using T = Foo<int, char, double>;

  using R = reverse_foo<T>::type;
  static_assert(std::is_same<Foo<double, char, int>, R>::value, ":(");
```

Comment: Op had non types in the list...  and wants partial reverse.  Op already has a typelist reverser.

Comment: I've already accomplished the above.  What I want to do is to reuse the above (or any transformation in fact--reversal is just an example) to make the same transformation for only part of (any) larger template structure.